# Vbs Multiple Line Email

Tags: email, vbscript

I am using a vbs file to send emails but it sends it in one line only. I want it to be multiple lines with & vbCRLF but it is not working for me.

Please help me with vbs emails with multiple line text.

My code :

```
Set emailObj      = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
emailObj.From     = "dc@gail.com"
emailObj.To       = "dc@gail.com"
emailObj.Subject  = "Test CDO"
emailObj.TextBody = "Test CDO" & vbCRLF & "Test CDO line 2"
Set emailConfig = emailObj.Configuration
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")    = 2  
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1  
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl")      = true 
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername")    = "YourUserName"
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword")    = "Password1"
emailConfig.Fields.Update
emailObj.Send
If err.number = 0 then Msgbox "Done"
```

Comment: Add your code in your question, it might be different from the answer linked.
Your email is in HTML? If yes have you tried with a <br />?

Comment: No i am not using HTML. I have updated my code. Please help !

Comment: This works fine for me in Outlook for Windows, Outlook for Mac and in the Gmail client.  Which mail client are you using to read the result?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it, just using ".HTMLBody" to be able to add formatting.  Works fine using outlook.

```
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
       Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
    with objMail
       .Display   'To display message
       .To = "test@test.com"
       .cc = "test@tested.com"
       .Subject = "FYI"
       .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY><p>Dear Team,</p><P> Please be informed, </p><P> Regards, </p><P><B> My Name </B><br><big><i>My Company</i> </big>(of awesomeness) </br></p></BODY></HTML>"


    end with
```